# Obtain the name of a Generic on compile time

Tags: typescript, generics, sequelize.js

### Question

Is there a way to do this:

```js
type Example<T> = { [nameof T]: T }
                     ^^^^^^
```

For example:

```js
class MyClass {}

// So it would look like (In compile-time):
Example<MyClass> = { 'MyClass': MyClass }
```

### Motive

The reason why I want to do it, it's because I'm working with Sequelize, and Sequelize automatically creates a reference to the Cross table when doing a Many-to-many relation. Like for example:

```
// Structure:
// User -- UserRole -- Role

// User object:
const user = User.find(...)
user.role[0].UserRole // <-- This object is based on the name of the Table
```

So my idea was to have a simple Mixin Type I could use to say:

```
class User {
    // Now role can now it has this property!
    role: Array<CrossReferenceOf<Role, UserRole>>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: no, there's no good way to do this.

---

In your example, the type named `MyClass` is the interface given to *instances* of `MyClass`.  As your example code has that defined without properties or methods, it is [equivalent](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) to the empty object type `{}`.  `MyClass` has no "name" property to speak of.  So there's no way to write `Example<MyClass>` and have the compiler produce `{MyClass: MyClass}` from it.

---

You might hope that the compiler could look at the name `MyClass` and convert it to the [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) `"MyClass"`, but that isn't the way the TS type system works.  TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) and *not* [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).  If two types in TypeScript have the same *structure* (properties and methods of the same types), then they are the same *type*.  On the other hand, just because two types in TypeScript are referred to by different *names* or have different *declarations*, it doesn't mean they are different *types*:

```
interface AlsoMyClass { }
var x: MyClass;
var x: AlsoMyClass; // <-- no error on redeclaration
```

Here you see that the `x` variable is redeclared with no error.  This indicates that the compiler sees `MyClass` and `AlsoMyClass` as the same type (try changing one of those to a type with a different structure and the second declaration will cause a compiler error).

So if `Example<MyClass>` could produce `{"MyClass": MyClass}`, then `Example<AlsoMyClass>` would *also* have to produce `{"MyClass": MyClass}` and *not* `{"AlsoMyClass": MyClass}`.  There's just no principled way to get a handle on the names given to types in TypeScript, at least with the `tsc` compiler.

---

One might also hope that instead of referring to the `MyClass` *instance* type, you could refer to the type of the `MyClass` *constructor*.  After all, at runtime, the `MyClass` *value* does have a `name` property which *should* be equal to `"MyClass"`.  So maybe you could have `Example<typeof MyClass>`, instead of `Example<MyClass>`.  If so, you could define `Example` like this:

```
type Example<T extends { name: string; new(...args: any): any }> =
    Record<T['name'], InstanceType<T>>;
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't really do it either.  The compiler only sees the `MyClass` constructor's `name` property as being of type `string`:

```
const myClassName = MyClass.name; // string
```

and so `Example<typeof MyClass>` is just `{[k: string]: MyClass}`; not good enough.

There's an open issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#32527](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32527) asking for the compiler to give string literal `name` properties to functions (such as class constructors) with known names, but it doesn't look like it's going to happen (especially because the `name` property might not be what you expect if you minify the code).

You can *try* to give `MyClass` a `static name` property, but the compiler doesn't like that either and you need to suppress the warning with `//@ts-ignore`:

```
class MyClass {
    //@ts-ignore 
    declare static readonly name: "MyClass";
}
```

This "works" in that `Example<typeof MyClass>` is `{MyClass: MyClass}`, but it is ugly and does not scale.

---

So unfortunately I'd say "no there's nothing great here".

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.1.2#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vQPS4AEAXCAWgEsBzAOwHsAnAU2ixwBNHQwnoIiwi5YNCZg2taiHjRqYALaMAXNABECZJAgqA3BgC+GDMAl9ocpCggA5ecwC8cC5oB0shdry5V6yysPlqIkZ6ADMwYGYAQRAIWh9NdGgDADduaAAPZXioXVT6DOVo2OyID3xoAB5SUhlaaGD6BmgJEUYOLnoBcglDQyJ4AAdmAFF0+QGQRgqAFXr0oOo2GDQZW2U+egDKD2pGAHcACmdj7koIZTBqeABKC6ukgD5oO1ZsACVOBjYZgG0AcjcjD+AF0ADTQACS1D4lwi00GU2mDweuiMJlok2cIFolAOJVctmuhmM0KI9WUo3Gkwq-SGtBCjg0UCeDhWfxKfyyTlQemgQA)

Comment: I feared it'd be this way :(. I might need to look into reflection libraries and some other form of preprocessing.